# I follow all steps of Unslider documentation but is not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I´ve read and follow the unslider documentation from here http://unslider.com/, but nothing appears in my page.
Is something missing?

html

```
<div class="banner">
    <ul>
        <li>This is a slide.</li>
        <li><img src="imagens/banner2 2.jpg" /></li>
        <li>This is a final slide.</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="unslider/unslider.min.js"> </script>
 <script type='text/javascript' src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
        $('.banner').unslider();
    });
</script>
```

CSS:

```
.banner { position: relative; overflow: auto; }
.banner li { list-style: none; }
.banner ul li { float: left; min-height:100px;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unslider is a jQuery plugin, so you'd have to include jQuery *before* you include the Unslider code, not the other way around. E.g.:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="unslider/unslider.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    $('.banner').unslider();
});
</script>
```

Comment: By the way, I'm looking for some information, maybe you know. Is there any specific size of images to the slider working as it should be? Because I have put pictures that I´ve here randomly and the images don´t take the 100% of the width and also the images are repeated.

Comment: I´ve added now this css .banner li { list-style: none; background-repeat:no-repeat; } and now the image dont repeat, but the image dont ocuppy the full width. So maybe there is a minimal size for the images?